# javascript - Creating bidirectional update in text entry areas

Tags: javascript, html

This is probably very simple but I seem to be running around in ever decreasing circles...

I'm developing a webpage for our payroll area and...

Q. Is it possible to have two text input fields that update each other automatically and will work in both directions. i.e one will update the other and vica-versa depending on input

What I'm after here...

Employees current salary is entered into a text input

Payroll can then enter data into one of two text inputs (New Salary or Percentage Increase)

Entering a New salary will automatically update **Percentage Increase** or
Entering a Percentage Increase will automatically update the **New Salary** field

The whole idea is to allow payroll to use either percentage or actual salary to
come up with the new figure

Thanks
Frankie G

Comment: What if a person (accidentally or otherwise) enters data in *both* fields, which field should win?

Comment: _"I seem to be running around in ever decreasing circles"_ - So you must be getting closer to the answer. Yes it is possible. Do you want to update on every keystroke, or just when focus leaves each field, or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a really basic implementation with no validation that the entered values are numeric:

```
window.onload = function() {    
    var currentSal = document.getElementById("current"),
        percentInc = document.getElementById("percent"),
        newSal = document.getElementById("new");

    percentInc.onkeyup = function() {
        newSal.value = currentSal.value * (1 + percentInc.value / 100);
    };
    newSal.onkeyup = function() {
        percentInc.value = (newSal.value - currentSal.value) / currentSal.value * 100;
    };    
};​
```

This assumes your html markup uses the element ids "current", "percent" and "new", but obviously you can change these. On any keyup within the percentage increase or new salary fields just do the appropriate calculation and update the other field. The whole thing is in an onload event for the page so that `document.getElementById()` can find the elements - you could, instead, put it in a script block at the end of the page (though having all contained in a function like that keeps the variables out of the global scope).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5pDdM/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement either the onChange method or the onkeyup.

Both are usable, though onChange gets fired when a user leaves the field and the input is changed, and onkeyup, whenever you release a key you pressed (Meaning, if you hold the button it won't fire, only after releasing).

Inside that function you could do something like

```
function salEntered(sal)
{
    document.getElementById("#perc").value = (document.getElementById("#origSal").value / sal )* 100;
}

function percEntered(perc){
    var new_sal = document.getElementById("#origSal").value * ( 1+ perc/100);
    document.getElementById("newSal").value = new_sal;
}
```

And bind those to either one of the named events. 
I took the perc as a whole decimal notation.

Bind them using :

```
<input type="text" id="newSal" onChange="salEntered(document.getElementById('newSal').value)" />
```

Or onkeyup.

Not able to test, will do later on, when I wake up.

When wrong, correct me. Using the var keyword keeps the variable in the correct scope , being the function.

Comment: @nnnnnn Your answer wasn't here yet when I started typing on mine. Typing that stuff goes slow on an iPhone with a diff dictionary than english :-)

Comment: Yeah, I've occasionally posted an answer from a smart phone, it's pretty frustrating when trying to enter code. Note that your statement _"and onChange, well, when it changes, on keystroke for example"_ isn't quite right: the change event doesn't happen on each keystroke, it is triggered when leaving the field (like blur, but only if a change has been made). Also `function`, `document` and `var` all need to begin with lowercase letters, though I'll bet you know that and it was your phone that made them uppercase...

Comment: @nnnnnn Indeed, changed the capitalization, thank you. And changed the events as well. Thanks for pointing out!.